# Full text search schedule throw an exception

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I try to create schedule for full text search, but when I choose Schedules menu I see this message:

[image]

I don't know how it can be affected with further error. The error happens when I press ok button on my schedule settings window.

[image]

How can I fix this error or can I add schedule by a TSQL script?

> ```
> ===================================
> ```
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (SqlManagerUI)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.FullTextIndexPropertiesSchedule.btnNew_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.RunningFormsTable.RunningFormsTableImpl.ThreadStarter.StartThread()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server Express edition, then Agent Job is not included.
Please, try upgrade to other editions(Standard, Enterprise etc..).